# Android: delete item from ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a problem with deleting items from ListView.

I am using a subclass of BaseExpandableListAdapter.

The problem is that when I am deleting an item, I change the underlying data, after which I call notifyDataSetChanged. All seems ok. But the refresh of the ListView does not happen immediately. So, if somebody keeps checking/un-cheking some of my items, they will point to data that there is no longer in adapter (but they are still displayed in the ListView).

**Example** :

Say I have a ListView with 3 views and 3 items in the adapter (1, 2, 3):

1. I select item 3 and press delete. Now they are 3 views and 2 items in the adapter
2. Call notifyDataSetChanged (note that the ListView still has 3 views since it did not had time to refresh)
3. I keep selecting the 3rd item which will query my adapter for an item which is no longer there

My question is how do I deal with this situation ? It seems to be a gap between the time the notifyDataSetChanged is called and the ListView is refreshed and within that gap, we need to check that all the requests received in the adapter are still valid.

Comment: `I keep selecting the 3rd item which will query my adapter for an item which is no longer there` So this is what you are seeing in the debugger? Is it crashing at this point? As Rajesh said, post your code.

Comment: Yes, it is crashing. I can prevent the crash from checking if the item  still exists, but I was wondering if it's the right way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your list item like.

```
filelist.remove("your selected item position".intValue());
```

This may solve your problem.